# Jmeter Test Fragment and Module Controller

Tags: jmeter

I have a Test Plan that contains the following:

**Test Fragment 1**

- BSF Sampler 1
- BSF Sampler 2

**Test Fragment 2**

- BSF Post Processor

**ThreadGroup 1**

- Module Controller 1 to call Test Fragment 1

**ThreadGroup 2**

- Sampler 1
- Sampler 2
- ...
- Sampler n
- Module Controller 2 to call Test Fragment 2

The first Test Fragment is called and executed successfully.
The issue is that Test Fragment 2 is either not called or not executed correctly.
Being a BSF Post Processor, this should be called after each Sampler in the ThreadGroup, and write in a file some variables.
This does not happen.

Could anyone shine some light on this and on why this would not work correctly?

The code from Test Fragment 2 works OK if I just put it in the ThreadGroup2, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the POST PROCESSOR concept.
It does not execute by itself, it only runs after a Sampler has run.
So it is absolutely regular that it does not execute since it is the only member of the Test Fragment. 
So switch to BSF Sampler instead.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors

Following your last comment, you will need to drop the Module Controller and Test Fragment.

Just put the Post Processor in the general scope , it will execute after each sampler, see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules

Comment: If I set it as a Sampler, I do not get the desired effect. The idea is to run the BSF script after EACH sampler in Thread Group 2

Comment: I don't know if I explained myself correctly. The BSF post processor from Test Fragment 2 will be needed to run after each Sampler. I wanted to create it in the Test Fragment because of 2 reasons: 1. I use many Thread Groups in one jmx file and 2. On certain runs, I need to disable the Test Fragment so that it does not run. If I put the BSF Post Processor in each Thread Group, enabling and disabling will be hard and tedious. Also, I want to be able to move the Test Fragment into a separate jmx file and use the Include Controller/Module Controller combo.

Comment: Yes, and my answer is I think the correct one, particularly after reading your update

Comment: To do what you want, just put your Post Processor as child of Thread Group 2.

Comment: So, from your answer I understand that I cannot use the Module Controller and Test Fragment in the way I need and the only way to use the Post Processor is to have it in the Thread Group.

Comment: You cannot have a Post Processor as the only child of a Test Fragment called from ModuleController as it will not be executed. You could if you only had a Sampler.